# Does the custom lua plugin for Apache APISIX support all phases of Nginx execution?

Tags: apache-apisix

Apache APISIX supports custom plugins, and I would like to know if I develop a `lua` plugin, at which stages of Nginx execution will it be injected, and does it support all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APISIX `lua` plugin supports code execution in the rewrite, access, before_proxy, header_filter, body_filter, and log phases of nginx. As shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221126193220/https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/tutorials/protect-api/):

[image]